# How to combine 2 lists containing csv strings and compare the result with another csv

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have the folowing list:

```
List<string> l1 = new List<string> { "A4,A2","A1,A3" };
List<string> l2 = new List<string> { "A5,A6", "A7,A8" };
```

I need to combine these 2 and create a list containing all of the items separated by comma, 
so I should end up with something containing:

> A4,A2,A1,A3,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9

I have used the following to combine the 2 lists:

```
string s1 = string.Join(",", l1.ToArray());
string s2 = string.Join(",", l2.ToArray());

var combinedItems = s1 + "," + s2;
```

Then I need to compare the result with another list to make sure it contains elements from A1 to A8

```
var allItems = new List<string> { "A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8" };

bool allItemsExist = allItems.Any(combinedItems.Contains);
```

This fails because ordering of **combinedItems** variable doesn't match the **allItems** ordering.

How can I sort the contents of **combinedItems** or is there another way of doing what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var items = new[] { l1, l2 }
            .SelectMany(x => x.SelectMany(y => y.Split(',')))
            .OrderBy(y => y);

var allItems = new List<string> 
                        { "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8" };

var result = allItems.SequenceEqual(items);
```

Answer (score 1):

brut solution:

```
      List<string> l1 = new List<string> { "A4,A2", "A1,A3" };
      List<string> l2 = new List<string> { "A5,A6", "A7,A8" };

      var s1 = string.Join(",", l1.ToArray());
      var s2 = string.Join(",", l2.ToArray());

      var combinedItems = s1 + "," + s2;
      var splittedAndOrderedCombinedItems = combinedItems.Split(',').OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

      var allItems = new List<string> { "A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8" };
      var firstOrDefault = allItems.FirstOrDefault();

      var splittedAllItems = new List<string>();
      if (firstOrDefault != null) {
        splittedAllItems = firstOrDefault.Split(',').ToList();
      }

      var result = splittedAllItems.Any(splittedAndOrderedCombinedItems.Contains);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and Dirty:

```
        var allItemsList = allItems.First().Split(',').ToList();
        var combinedItemsList = combinedItems.Split(',').ToList();

        bool allItemsExists = combinedItemsList.All(x => allItemsList.Contains(x));
```

It makes no sense to save the comma seperated string as one item in a list, so make a REAL list out of it.

My last statement determines if every Item (A1-A8) is contained in the allItemsList.

PS: `allItemsExists` returns `true` in my test.

Answer (score 0):

You could split all items:

```
List<string> l1 = new List<string> { "A4,A2", "A1,A3" }.SelectMany(x => x.Split(',')).ToList();
List<string> l2 = new List<string> { "A5,A6", "A7,A8" }.SelectMany(x => x.Split(',')).ToList();

string combinedItems = string.Join(",", l1.Concat(l2));

List<string> allItems = new List<string> { "A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8" }.SelectMany(x => x.Split(',')).ToList();

bool allItemsExist = allItems.All(combinedItems.Contains);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split all strings to their "A1" "A2" parts, sort them and join them.

```
    List<string> l1 = new List<string> { "A4,A2", "A1,A3" };
    List<string> l2 = new List<string> { "A5,A6", "A7,A8" };
    var result = l1.SelectMany(x => x.Split(',')).Union(l2.SelectMany(x => x.Split(','))).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
    var str = string.Join("," , result);
    str.Dump();
```

Output:

```
A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8
```